# Regular Expression for Validating Bitcoin Addresses

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to write a function that returns true or false if it's a valid bitcoin address.

I currently have a QR Code Scanner that returns a string like this:

bitcoin:18YCdhPsd5gdf6WD4ioMZZJKTNdajUJyTM

Here's my function:

```
func isValidBitcoinAddress() -> Bool {
    var fullAddress = self.components(separatedBy: ":")
    let r = fullAddress[1].startIndex..<fullAddress[1].endIndex
    let pattern = "^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"
    let r2 = self.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression)
    if r2 == r {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is returning false every time.

I got the RegEx patter from this site: http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2014/11/21/regex-bitcoin.html

Is the format perhaps different in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: `fullAddress[1].startIndex..<fullAddress[1].endIndex` -> `fullAddress[1].indices`

Comment: This seems like a weak type. Rather than adding a method to `isValidBitcoinAddress` to `String`, consider making a struct called `BitcoinAddress`, which wraps a `String`, and provides a failable initializer that succeeds iff the string provided to it is a valid address. From there, your app can work with only `BitcoinAddress` instances, and can be certain they will be valid addresses, rather than using strings and having to check all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `self` to the pattern instead of `fullAddress[1]`.

Use the following:

```
func isValidBitcoinAddress() -> Bool {
    let fullAddress = self.components(separatedBy: ":")
    if fullAddress.count == 2 && fullAddress[0] == "bitcoin" {
        let pattern = "^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"
        let r = fullAddress[1].startIndex..<fullAddress[1].endIndex
        let r2 = fullAddress[1].range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression)
        return r == r2
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote for an answer that actually works and solves the problem?

Answer (score 2):

@rmaddy and @Alexander have answered your question.

I am just adding my implemented code:

```
func isValidBitcoinAddress(stringBitCoinID:String) -> Bool {
    let fullAddress = stringBitCoinID.components(separatedBy: ":")

    guard fullAddress.count == 2, fullAddress[0] == "bitcoin" else {
        return false
    }

    let r = fullAddress[1]
    let pattern = "^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"

    let bitCoinIDTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern)
    let result = bitCoinIDTest.evaluate(with: r)

    return result
}
```

Comment: This code will crash for any string that doesn't have a `:` in it.

Comment: Sorry @rmaddy didn't check that scenario. Adding `guard` statement will do ?

Comment: An error arises on the line let result = bitCoinIDTest.evaluate(with: r) for conflicting types.

Comment: I used this code in swift 3.2 using your Bitcoin string and it return yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the regex on only the part after the `:`:

```
extension String {
    func isValidBitcoinAddress() -> Bool {
        let addressComponents = self.components(separatedBy: ":")
        guard addressComponents.count == 2,
              addressComponents[0] == "bitcoin" else {
            return false
        }

        let address = addressComponents[1]

        let pattern = "^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$"
        let range = address.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression)
        return range == address.indices
    }
}
```